# InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression is [object Attr]. It should be an element using XPath Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

[image: Here is the html]
Hi I want to locate the href element connected to a student named "John Doe" based on the `following-sibling` input value of 'ST'. This the code im using to select the element:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[following-sibling::input[@value="ST"]]/@href').click()
```

It's locating the correct element but im getting this error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//a[following-sibling::input[@value="ST"]]/@href" is: [object Attr]. It should be an element.
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: When you have text output, [don't take a picture but copy paste the output in your POST](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text) The html can be copied as well from within the browser console: from inspector, right click -> copy as outerHTML.

Comment: You can't select attribute nodes, they are not implemented as separate objects. Select the `<a>` element itself and then grab the attribute value with Python code.

Comment: aren't I selecting the `<a>` in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "//a[following-sibling::input[@value="ST"]]/@href" is: [object Attr]. It should be an element.
```

......implies that your *XPath* expression was not a valid *xpath expression*.

---

For the record
[Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) supports *xpath-1.0* only which returns the set of node(s) selected by the *xpath*.

> You can find the [xpath-1.0](/questions/tagged/xpath-1.0) specifications in [XML Path Language (XPath) Version 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/)

Where as the *xpath* expression you have used:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[following-sibling::input[@value="ST"]]/@href')
```

Is a *xpath-2.0* based expression and would typically return an `object Attr`. A couple of examples:

- `//@version`: selects all the version attribute nodes that are in the same document as the context node
- `../@lang`: selects the lang attribute of the parent of the context node

> You can find the [xpath-2.0](/questions/tagged/xpath-2.0) specifications in [XML Path Language (XPath) 2.0 (Second Edition)](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/)

---

### Solution

To locate the desired element with a *href* attribute connected to a student named "John Doe" based on the following-sibling input value of **ST** you can use either of the following [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) based [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using *preceding*:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='ST']//preceding::a[1]").click()
  ```
- Using *preceding-sibling*:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='ST']//preceding-sibling::a[@href]").click()
  ```

Comment: I am not an expert on xpath but it seems if you reach an attribute you can always access its parent element by adding a /.. [slash double dot] at the end i.e. : `"//@*[name()='xml:id' and .='corr1']/.."`